# Login is successful even if it is invalid user

Tags: flutter, validation, authentication, sqflite

I simply want to accept username and password while login and check in the database if user is valid or not but the problem is for any username and password it shows "login successful". Whatever values I give it shows login successful but it should show "user doesnt exist." Please help me.

db_service.dart

```
Future<RegisterUser> getLogin(String user, String password) async {
    await DB.init();
    var res = await DB.rawQuery("userDetails WHERE emailId = '$user' and password = '$password'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return RegisterUser.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

UserLogin.dart (Code for the login button)

```
bool validateAndSave() {

    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  void _submit(){
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    var res;
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      setState(() {
        res=dbService.getLogin(_email, _password).then((value) {
          if(res!=0){
            FormHelper.showMessage(
              context,
              "Login",
              "Login Successfull",
              "Ok",
                  () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => People_List(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );}
          else {
            FormHelper.showMessage(
                context,
                "Login",
                "Login not Successfull",
                "Ok", () {}

            );
          }
        });
      });


    }
  }
```

Comment: What does this line do `if(res!=0)`? Probably you wanted to write `if(value != null)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the Future function in the wrong way.

```
res= await dbService.getLogin(_email, _password);
if(res != 0){

} else {

}
```

Or

```
dbService.getLogin(_email, _password).then((value) {
  if(value != 0){

  }else {

  }
}, onError(e){});
```